# Scala type mismatch while doing pattern matching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I am trying to do a pattern matching which is working as expected but IntelliJ IDE is showing the below highlighting error

> ```
> Expected: PartialFunction[Regex, NotInferedB], actual: Nothing => Boolean. 
> Cannot resolve method x.unapply  
> Cannot resolve symbol x
> ```

Code:

```
 scala>  val keys = Map(
         |          "XYZ" -> List("(?i)(.*SANDWICH.*)",
         |            "(?i)(.*BURGER.*)").map(x => x.r)
         |        )

    keys: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[scala.util.matching.Regex]] = Map(XYZ -> List((?i)(.*SANDWICH.*), (?i)(.*BURGER.*)))

    scala> val desc = "I DON't LIKE SANDWICH "
    desc: String = "I DON't LIKE SANDWICH "

    scala> if (keys("XYZ").collect{x => desc match{ case x(key) => true}}.contains(true)) println("yes") else println("no")
    yes
```

The error is showing in the collect part. Can anyone please guide me as what might be the issue that is causing the highlighting error in IntelliJ

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting `PartialFunction[Regex, NotInferedB], actual: Nothing => Boolean` compile time because you are giving lambda function whereas the `collect` function takes the PartialFunction.

I don't know what you wanted to achieve with the snippet of code but below will resolve your problem.

```
if (keys("XYZ").collect { case x => true }.contains(true)) println("yes") else println("no")
```

Answer (score 0):

- This is the right way to write you last expression is:

`if (keys("XYZ").collect{case x: Regex => desc match{ case x(_) => true} 
  }.contains(true)) println("yes") else println("no")`

- But there is a better way to write it :

  `if(keys("XYZ").exists { x => x.findFirstMatchIn(desc) match {
  case Some(_) => true
  case None => false
      }
     }) println("yes") else println("no")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`if (keys("XYZ").exists(_.findFirstIn(desc).isDefined)) println("yes") else println("no")`